# How can I return an array/record set of my own structure form Oracle’s procedure

Tags: c++, sql, oracle

I am new in Oracle and have a problem. We like to write a procedure which will read data from a table and do some processing on each row and then return the resultant data. Its means the resultant data will have same number of rows but each column type can’t be same. Here this procedure I want to use like a C++ function which return a vector of structure.

TABLE structure is as follows

```
FIRST int
Second VARCHAR2(20)
Third int
```

Then the return structure would be

```
FIRST int
Second int
Third int;
Fourth int;
```

In short how can I return an array/record set of my own data structure form Oracle’s procedure.

Comment: Looking into pipeline/piping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do it:

- Table function:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION <YOUR_NAME_OF_FUNCTION> (...) 
    RETURN <TABLE_TYPE> AS
      l_table   := ();
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. N
      LOOP
        l_table.extend;
        l_table(l_table.last) := (some, data, for, table, type);
      END LOOP;
      RETURN l_tab;
    END;
```

- Pipelined table function

```
CREATE FUNCTION <YOUR_NAME_OF_FUNCTION> (...) 
RETURN <TABLE_TYPE> PIPELINED AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. N
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW((some, data, for, table, type));
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
```

to select from this functions:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE(<YOUR_NAME_OF_FUNCTION>(...))
```

`<TABLE_TYPE>` is something like:

```
CREATE tab_type is table of NUMBER(10)
```

Pipelined functions have to work faster than table function, because they return every row as the row is prepared, table function prepare all rows and then return them at once.
To read more check [this article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php)

Comment: Thanks ZARATUSRA!!  Your example helped me a lot.